# BasicTomcat authentication failed

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

today i set up a Windows VM and a Tomcat Server on Windows Azure. 
Now i want to authentificate on my Tomcat. I open the adress http://127.0.0.1:8080/ and the internet Explorer ask me for my authentification.

In the tomcat-user.xml file is the following user configured:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

But I cant authentificate me with this credentials. The authentification dialog appears again.

Can you help me with this problem? have i done somenthing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart tomcat after changing the tomcat-user.xml

Comment: This question should be moved to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart the server after changing the .xml files, because Tomcat reads the files at launch, not at runtime.